# Powershell command to FTP a file from server to select PCs on a network

Tags: powershell, ftp

TLDR: I need to move a large file from a server to the desktop of multiple SELECT machines connected to it.

Network topography:

- 1 Server
- 5 - 20 Connected PCs

This topography is pretty standard across all remote networks that I work on. On some occasions, I have to put files on each machine on a network; sometimes only on a few individual machines that site admins utilize.

I keep a 'master copy' of the file on the server at all times, and currently RDPing into each machine i need it on (once I resolve the IP to make sure they aren't printers/tablets/phones/etc...) and copy over the file where I need it from the server to the connected machine (the directory is standard). After researching, I think a PS script would probably work for what I need but I only know enough to be dangerous.

I use the following to resolve IPs to host names so I can determine which machines I need to put it on:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "xNext="
set "xComputer="
for /f %%A in ('net view /all') do (
set "xComputer=%%~A"
if "!xComputer:~0,2!"=="\\" for /f "tokens=2,* delims=. " %%X in ('nslookup %%A') do (
    if "!xNext!"=="1" (
        echo.!xComputer! = %%X.%%Y
        set "xNext=0"
    )
    if "!xComputer:~2!"=="%%~X" set "xNext=1"
)
)
endlocal
pause
```

I want the ability to use the output of this code to build a list of IPs, then FTP the file to the IPs to a common directory `C:/Folder` . I could build a `ComputerList.txt` with the IPs and use it but I'm not quite sure how to integrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just needing to copy a file locally you don't need FTP, you can use a copy command (copy, xcopy, robocopy). 
Create a powershell array from your objects, then use the foreach cmdlet and use robocopy to copy the file to each of the workstations. Something line like:

```
Get-Content c:\machines_List.txt | Foreach-Object {robocopy c:\source \\$_\c$\folder filename.exe"}
```

Comment: Assuming they are domain joined

Comment: This worked beautifully! Exactly what i was needing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully you don't need to recreate the wheel here. Use WinSCP. Here's the link to the documentation:

[WinSCP - Using from PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#using_from_powershell)

If you need assistance after looking at this documentation, let me know by leaving a comment.

Comment: I got this to work for one machine at a time, I couldnt quite figure out how to add a list of IPs to push the file across the network all at once